# Popover / ActionSheet styling to match system apps?

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller, look-and-feel

I'm hoping somebody can help me... I want to use popovers (or actionsheets displayed as popovers) in the iPad app I'm working on.

The problem I'm having is making them look the way I want.  I want my popovers to look like the standard ones used in a number of the core Apps.

I'm having particular problems getting a white heading over the background gradient as you get in the popover that is part of the split view, or the "Printer Options" popover.

Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to present an action sheet in a popover is the following:

```
-(IBAction)moreActions:(UIBarButtonItem *)it{
    UIActionSheet *act = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"What should we do?" 
                                                     delegate:self 
                                            cancelButtonTitle:nil 
                                       destructiveButtonTitle:nil 
                                            otherButtonTitles:@"Render Video (again)",@"Share Story",@"Email Story",@"YouTube",@"Save to Library",nil];

    act.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;
    [act showFromBarButtonItem:it animated:YES];
    [act release];
}
```

This will show the UIActionSheet inside a popover from the **it** UIBarButtonItem. This looks exactly like in the core apps. If you are not presenting from a UIBarButtonItem use the - (void)showFromRect:(CGRect)rect inView:(UIView *)view animated:(BOOL)animated method to present from an arbitrary frame.

Is this what you are doing?

Comment: Yup, that's pretty much where I'd got to.  Unfortunately the title comes out very small and grey (compared to the system apps), and I'm then limited to using Buttons for controls, when I really want a mixture of labels, textfields, and a textview.

Comment: Could you post an image of the difference?

Comment: I mean, of course for other UI elements you need to build a custom view. But what is the graphical difference?

Comment: I should be able to... [The different appearances of the titles](http://www.speedorigami.co.uk/temp/PopoverTitles.png) (on the left is the ActionSheet and on the right the same text from a system popover - both from the Simulator)

Comment: I'm also not sure we're allowed to have custom views inside of UIActionSheet.